# How can I map a dictionary of dicitionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've the following dictionary:

```
dict_league_position = {
   20 : {
      "Defender" : 20,
      "Forward" : 30
   },
   24 : {
      "Defender" : 50,
      "Forward" : 10
   },
}
```

I'd like to compute the column `value` inside the following DataFrame by using the dictionary values:

| idx | tournament | position | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | Defender |  |
| 2 | 20 | Defender |  |
| 3 | 20 | Forward |  |
| 4 | 20 | Forward |  |
| 5 | 24 | Forward |  |
| 6 | 24 | Defender |  |

Could I do this by using map? Any suggest?

Comment: Any suggest in case I've one more dictionary concatenated? So 3 concat dictionary and 3 columns to use a condition?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by `MultiIndex Series` created by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = pd.DataFrame(dict_league_position).stack().rename('value')
df = df.join(s,on=['position','tournament'])
print (df)
   tournament  position  value
1          20  Defender     20
2          20  Defender     20
3          20   Forward     30
4          20   Forward     30
5          24   Forward     10
6          24  Defender     50
```